# accurately predicting behavior from initial brain state

Tags: brain

so according to mainstream view brains are completely deterministic given initial conditions and knowing all the external input, and free will doesn't exist. so has there been attempts to predict human/advanced animal behavior from a given initial brain state? i mean accurately predicting movement of limbs and words spoken and facial expression for many minutes, not just predicating a sad brain is going to cry.

Comment: I think you are mixing up a bunch of different concepts. There are a bunch of different [neural coding schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_coding) and many of these include a non-deterministic component (or require the state to be specified at the/molecular/atomic level).

Comment: This is more of a philosophical question (or possibly a physics one) about what is and is not deterministic. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/45662/can-i-predict-my-future-by-observing-all-humans-events is an example. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_demon I am not aware of a "mainstream view" that "brains are completely deterministic" so I'd also be curious where that view is coming from.